# WP_Query exclude posts using meta query

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't wrap my head around this one, would appreciate some help!

**Overview**
I have a "news" page with two seperate WP_Query loops. The first loop at the top of the page contains the 2 latest "featured" posts, defined by the following conditions;

```
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'posts_per_page' => 2,
      'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
          'key'       => 'featured_post',
          'value'     => 'yes',
          'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The "featured_post" key relates to a custom ACF checkbox field. The client uses this to define featured posts in the backend of Wordpress.

Now in the second WP_Query loop, the remaining posts are displayed using the following conditions;

```
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'    => array(
          array(
            'key'       => 'featured_post',
            'value'     => 'yes',
            'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE',
          ),
        ),
      );
```

This essentially excludes the featured posts from this second loop.

**Problem**
My issue is the client doesn't always remember to untick the "featured" ACF field from the old featured posts when adding a new one. Therefore older featured posts that are no longer meant to be featured don't shift into the second loop.

Is there a way to use the meta_query in the second loop to exclude only the two latest featured posts - instead of all of them?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.
**First,** 
 create a function on function.php like this:

```
<?php 
function exclude_featured_post_IDs(){
    $featured_post_IDs = array();
    $args_featured = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'     =>'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured_post',
                'value' => '"yes"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            )
        );
        $query_featured = new WP_Query($args_featured);
        if ($query_featured->have_posts()) :
            while ($query_featured->have_posts()) :
                $query_featured->the_post();
                array_push($featured_post_IDs, get_the_ID());   
                
    ?>
<?php
            
    endwhile;
    endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

return $featured_post_IDs;
    
} ?>
```

**Then,** 
 Use this parameter ***'post__not_in' => exclude_featured_post_IDs(),*** in the second WP_Query loop:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        **'post__not_in' => exclude_featured_post_IDs(),**
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
      );
?>
```